# Understanding Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to learn c# at work and I'm not really sure how to use Automapper at the same time.  There is this extension method that is being used other areas of the site. I tried to use it on another C# class.

```
    public static TResult MapTo<TResult>(this object self)
    {
        if (self == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        return (TResult)Mapper.Map(self, self.GetType(), typeof(TResult));
    }
```

I get the exception "An exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' occurred in AutoMapper.dll but was not handled in user code."  Then when I look at the inner exception it says, "Trying to map BlahEntity to BlahResponse."  I'm not really sure how to go about debugging this.  Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you created a map for your objects?  If you're just getting started with Automapper you can read this: https://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started

Comment: @squillman No I didn't create the map yet.  I didn't know I needed to.  Will look at the wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will first need to "Create" the mapping between objects, even if there is no customization going on with the mappings. For example :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DomainObject, DTOObject>();
```

Note that this is a one way map, to go back the other way you need to map it in the other direction. Be aware there is plenty of blogs/posts/answers out there on why you should only go from Domain->DTO and not the other way, but for other types of objects in your app it should be fine. So :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DTOObject,DomainObject>();
```

Using no customizations, Automapper uses conventions to decide how these objects relate to each other. For example if both objects have a field called "CustomerName" then it's obvious that these should be mapped automatically.

There are other options to create custom ways in which objects can relate to each other. For example in our DTO we may want to only have "CustomerName" but in our Domain model we have "FirstName" and "LastName". We can create a special mapping config to automatically concatenate these two when we map the objects.

Check out the documentation here for Automapper : https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki